# How to test Facebook JS SDK sign in using Cucumber?

Tags: facebook, selenium, cucumber

I'm trying to figure out how to write a Cucumber test which tests my Facebook sign in and that my application responds correctly in different scenarios. However, when I launch the app (with Selenium) and click the sign in button, it opens the Facebook sign in pop up window, but Facebook displays an error that the app is not running on a subdomain of the app's production domain. I'm not sure how to either get Facebook to work in this testing environment, or to mock the Facebook request/response.

How can I test Facebook login using Cucumber?

Comment: what is the exact error message? did you add the domain of your test environment in the app settings? you can also use localhost btw.

Comment: The error message: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

The app host is 127.0.0.1 and running on a random port that was started by Cucumber.

Comment: When I try to add 127.0.0.1 to the App Domains on Facebook, I get this error: App domains must match the domain of the Secure Canvas URL, Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Please correct these domains: 127.0.0.1

Comment: I also tried to add the localhost domain, but got the same error. I also tried creating a test app under the Test Apps section, but I got the same results when trying to add my test domains.

Comment: well, then, add a website URL and add localhost. you MUST have at least one platform. try with the exact same port.

Comment: @luschn I don't understand. Isn't that what I tried? Facebook won't let me add localhost.

Comment: i will add an answer with working settings.

Comment: done. if that does not work, please add a screenshot of your app settings and any error message you get after trying to save them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the domain to your App Settings.

In the "Settings" tab, add the platform "Website" with the following URL: http://localhost:3000/ (replace the port with your port, of course)

In the "App Domains" field, just add "localhost".

Comment: I found out that Facebook requires you to specify the port that the app is running on. I was able to get this to work by hard-coding the host and port that Capybara uses to spin up the app server. `Capybara.server_host = "localhost"; Capybara.server_port = "54321"`.

Comment: yes, of course. that´s why i added the port in my answer :)